# Shorthand or sugar for declaring multiple variables with same value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntactic-sugar, shorthand

I was wondering if there is a shorthand in ES6 or Babel to declare multiple variables with the same value, e.g. when using multiple refs in React:

```
const a = React.useRef();
const b = React.useRef();
const c = React.useRef();
const d = React.useRef();
....
```

But also in vanilla JS when declaring an object with multiple keys with the value null:

```
const obj = { a: null, b:null, c:null, d:null }
```

So I thought maybe there is something like

`const a, b, c, d, = React.useRef();`

Thanks

Comment: `let [a, b, c, d] = Array(4).fill(2);` probably not the best

Comment: It's easy if you wanted primitives... `let a, b, c, d; a = b = c = d = null;`
But that trick doesn't work for objects, because they would all be pointers to the same object, and changing one would change all of them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no full-shorthand but You can make it a little simple just by writing it like this-

```
let [a,b,c,d] =  [React.useRef(),React.useRef(),React.useRef(),React.useRef()]
```

This will at least compress those codes in a line.

Comment: right hand side can be simplified as [...Array(4)].map(React.useRef)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

`const a=b=c="some value";`